# Javascript: Exporting data from an array to a HTML table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html-table

I have a twodimensional array of Strings like:

```
[["Application1", "11106.exampleserver.com", "11109.exampleserver.com", "11102.exampleserver.com", "11105.exampleserver.com" "Database, AFPUOR(KNAJKLD)", "Database, UOQZRNJ(LKUJD)" ],
 ["Application2", "44407.exampleserver.com", "11106.exampleserver.com", "11104.exampleserver.com", "Database, POJPR (OIUOLWA) ", "Database, UIAHSD (JJJQEP)" ],...]
```

and so on.. (everytime different number of server/databases)

How can I sort the "applications" by database/server and show/save these databases/servers?
Whats the best way of managing the array?

**I need an HTML table: In the table head the name of the Application and then the Servers and Databases (I need to divide servers and databases).**

Right now I am able to output Databases with this code:

```
for(j=0; j < columns.length; j++){
    for(i=0;i < columns[j].length; i++){
        var db = columns[j][i].match("Database")
        if (db != null){
            console.log("APP: " +  j + ": " + columns[j][0] + " , ID: " + i + ": " + db.input)
            //outpus e.g.: APP: 0: Application1, ID: 5: Database XYZ
        }
    }
}
```

and Servers with this code:

```
for(j=0; j < columns.length; j++){
    for(i=1;i < columns[j].length; i++){
        var db = columns[j][i].match("Database")
        if (db == null){
            console.log("APP: " +  j + ": " + columns[j][0] + " , ID: " + i + ": " + columns[j][i])
            //outpus e.g.: APP: 0: Application1, ID: 1: Server1.1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited it: Thats how my array looks like.

Comment: So applications always start with "Application", databases with "Database" and servers with "Server"?

Comment: No thats just my example now. They all have different names: Applications with spaces inbetween and always different, Servers for example 124131.server.com and Databases like: "Database, UIAHSD (JJJQEP)

Comment: Can you show a sample input with a sample expected output? It's not clear what `sort the "applications" by database/server and show/save these databases/servers` means exactly.

Comment: Thats what I need to figure out when I know how to manage the data. I need to show which Application has which Servers and Databases in a table, and then I need to compare them with another list of servers to see if they are in the list (array) or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have tried to group the data by application and then by type:

```
var d = [["Application1", "11106.exampleserver.com", "11109.exampleserver.com", "11102.exampleserver.com", "11105.exampleserver.com", "Database, AFPUOR(KNAJKLD)", "Database, UOQZRNJ(LKUJD)"], ["Application2", "44407.exampleserver.com", "11106.exampleserver.com", "11104.exampleserver.com", "Database, POJPR (OIUOLWA) ", "Database, UIAHSD (JJJQEP)"]];

var data = {};

for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    data[d[i][0]] = {
        Server: [],
        Database: []
    };
    console.log(d[i][0]);
    for (var j = 1; i < d[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(d[i][j]);
        if (typeof d[i][j] == 'undefined')
            break;

        if (d[i][j].match('Database')) {
            data[d[i][0]]['Database'].push(d[i][j]);
        } else {
            data[d[i][0]]['Server'].push(d[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Output:

```
{
    "Application1": {
        "Server": [
            "11106.exampleserver.com", 
            "11109.exampleserver.com", 
            "11102.exampleserver.com", 
            "11105.exampleserver.com"
        ], 
        "Database": [
            "Database, AFPUOR(KNAJKLD)", 
            "Database, UOQZRNJ(LKUJD)"
        ]
    }, 
    "Application2": {
        "Server": [
            "44407.exampleserver.com", 
            "11106.exampleserver.com", 
            "11104.exampleserver.com"
        ], 
        "Database": [
            "Database, POJPR (OIUOLWA) ", 
            "Database, UIAHSD (JJJQEP)"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and motified it with my notation but after a few applications it stops to save the server and database (so half of the application with its servers and databases are empty..?) It just stops to save them

Comment: I have no idea what is causing this... Do you maybe have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this out,

**in your html**

```
<table >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Application</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Database</th>
                <th>Server</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**in your javascript**

```
const table = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

data.forEach((entity,index) => {

    let rowData = {}

    rowData.applicationName = entity[0]
    rowData.id = index
    rowData.databases = []
    rowData.servers = []

    entity.forEach(value => {

        if (value.match('Database')){
            rowData.databases.push(value)        
        }else{
            rowData.servers.push(value)   
        }

    })

    appendRow(rowData)
})


function appendRow(rowData) {

    table.innerHTML +=  `<tr>
        <td>${rowData.applicationName}</td>
        <td>${rowData.id}</td>
        <td>${rowData.databases.join(',')}</td>
        <td>${rowData.servers.join(',')}</td>    
    </tr>`

}
```

hope this helps!